Astro website will not navigate pages after adding PWA integration
I've been developing an Astro website with the intent of converting to a PWA. I am using the @vite-pwa/astro package for this. Once I added in the PWA stuff, site navigation ceased to work. When I click a link to go to a different page, I see the page load animation in the browser, the link updates in the browser, but the page doesn't change.
Here is my Astro config:
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import vercel from "@astrojs/vercel/serverless";
import pwa from "@vite-pwa/astro";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  site: "https://example.org",
  output: "server",
  integrations: [
    tailwind({
      applyBaseStyles: false,
    }),
    react(),
    pwa({
      mode: import.meta.env.MODE,
      base: '/',
      scope: '/',
      includeAssets: ['favicon.ico'],
      registerType: 'autoUpdate',
      manifest: {
        name: 'My Site',
        short_name: 'My Site',
        theme_color: '#ffffff',
        icons: [
          {
            "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "src": "android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
          }
        ],
      },
      workbox: {
        navigateFallback: '/',
        globPatterns: ['**/*.{css,js,html,svg,png,ico,txt}'],
      },
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateFallbackAllowlist: [/^\//],
      },
      experimental: {
        directoryAndTrailingSlashHandler: true,
      }
    }),
  ],
  adapter: vercel(),
});


I have updated my root layout to include a script for the pwa.ts and pwaInfo stuff as per the documentation:
---
import "~/styles/globals.css";

import { getNavLinks } from "~/lib/payload";
import Footer from "./footer.astro";
import Navbar from "./navbar.astro";
import { pwaInfo } from 'virtual:pwa-info';

const navlinks = await getNavLinks();
---

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico" />
    <link
        rel="apple-touch-icon"
        sizes="180x180"
        href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"
    />
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon.ico" color="#FFFFFF" />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <slot name="head" />

    <!-- pwa stuff -->
    <script src="/src/pwa.ts"></script>
    { pwaInfo && <Fragment set:html={pwaInfo.webManifest.linkTag} /> }
  </head>
  <body>
    <Navbar navlinks={navlinks} />
    <main id="main">
      <slot />
    </main>
    <Footer navlinks={navlinks} />
  </body>
</html>


The pwa.ts is unchanged from the documentation:

import { registerSW } from 'virtual:pwa-register'

registerSW({
  immediate: true,
  onRegisteredSW(swScriptUrl: any) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('SW registered: ', swScriptUrl)
  },
  onOfflineReady() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log('PWA application ready to work offline')
  },
})

If I add the ViewTransitions component to the root layout to use SPA mode, the pages properly navigate, but upon refresh it returns to the home page. On top of that, sometimes the React islands I am using stop working.
In case this is important, the website is using PayloadCMS for all page content and a modified version of the SSR [...slug].astro page in the Astro docs.

I just run into a similar issue (page reloads would always render the offline page) and could solve it by writing the SW myself in src/service-worker.ts:
import { cleanupOutdatedCaches, precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { offlineFallback } from 'workbox-recipes';
import { setDefaultHandler } from 'workbox-routing';
import { NetworkOnly } from 'workbox-strategies';

declare let self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

cleanupOutdatedCaches();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly());
offlineFallback({ pageFallback: 'offline' });

Didn't change the registerSW({...}) and I am using PWA assets generator and PWA info to include everything in my base layout:
import { pwaAssetsHead } from 'virtual:pwa-assets/head';
import { pwaInfo } from 'virtual:pwa-info';
---
<head>
  <script src="/src/pwa.ts"></script>
  {pwaAssetsHead.themeColor &&
      <meta name="theme-color" content={pwaAssetsHead.themeColor.content} />}
  {pwaAssetsHead.links.map(link => ( <link {...link} /> ))}
  {pwaInfo && <Fragment set:html={pwaInfo.webManifest.linkTag} />}
</head>

The workbox configuration has to be adjusted to include the custom worker (note everything from strategies to injectManifest and devOptions.type):
import pwa from '@vite-pwa/astro';
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import { seoConfig } from './seo-config';

export default defineConfig({
  site: seoConfig.baseURL,
  integrations: [
    ...
    pwa({
      manifestFilename: 'manifest.json',
      manifest: { ... },
      pwaAssets: { ... },
      registerType: 'prompt',
      strategies: 'injectManifest',
      srcDir: 'src',
      filename: 'service-worker.ts',
      injectManifest: {
        globDirectory: 'dist',
        globPatterns: [
          'offline/**/*.html',
          '**/*.{js,css,svg,webp,woff,woff2,ttf,eot,ico}',
        ],
        globStrict: true,
      },
      devOptions: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateFallback: undefined,
        type: 'module',
      },
      experimental: {
        directoryAndTrailingSlashHandler: true,
      }
    }),
  ],
});

